# How to remove the domestic cold water valve body to replace the seal?

Tags: plumbing

Can't turn off domestic cold water completely, under the kitchen sink. How to remove the valve body to get access to the washer? So far, I've backed the nut off the external threads.

[image: valve]

Comment: If you turn(same direction to open the valve) the handle it should just turn out.  I am assuming you have turn off the main or a valve before this point.

Comment: Water is off in the basement, yes. CCW opens?  It won't budge in either direction. Do I apply leverage?

Comment: I was able to get the valve to turn with a pair of large pliars, but when it is backed all the way out, it reaches an impasse. Afraid to bust it by turning too hard.

Comment: Check carefully behind the nut still on the body for a seam.  The big nut might unscrew also if there is a seam.  A very good cleaning might be needed to see.

Comment: I'd be inclined to at least blather it in WD 40 or specialist penetrating oil & see if you fare any better tomorrow. There's a lot of crud there. If the washer's end-of-life squashed to all heck, it could be jamming the barrel too. Make sure it's at least well-lubed, then give it a *bit* more force tomorrow.

Comment: There appears to be a seam but it's not budging. I think it will be easier to replace the piping and install new quarter-turn shutoff valves.

Comment: It could be a gate valve, which does not have a replaceable washer. You have to undo the big nut to remove the works inside, not the small packing nut around the stem. Doing so will probably not be of any use, gate valves are notorious for not shutting off completely, and should never be used for fixture shut-off valves.